# AddImageUrl in Abcpdf throwing error

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I am using Abcpdf 8.1 to convert html page to pdf. But i am getting below error

Unable to render HTML. Unable to access URL COM error 800c0019 in FACILITY_INTERNET. The drive cannot locate a specific area or track on the disk. URL

I have a webiste which expose a webservice. This webservice has code to use Abcpdf API. The html page is exposed from another website which is over https.
the webservice uses the html page usign the https website. When i exposed the html page over http, conversion works fine